# Access to paperclip temp file when using s3 storage option on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I am using the Paperclip gem to resize upload photos and store them on amazon S3.  I need access to the resized photo to also pass along to another web service, during the lifecycle of the upload request.

I suspect there is a temp file created somewhere the imagemagik uses before the photo is uploaded to s3.  How can I get access to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Paperclip readme](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) there're a few callbacks that it calls after and before processing.

For **each** attachment:

- before_post_process
- after_post_process

Only for a **specific** attachment:

- before_[attachment]_post_process
- after_[attachment]_post_process

I think in your case you should use one of the `after` callbacks to get the resized photo. Then you should be able to access the file with `queued_for_write`. For example:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "300x300>" }
  after_post_process :send_photo

  private
  def send_photo
    path = photo.queued_for_write[:small].path
    # upload the photo to the ws here
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this looks like what I was looking for.  The piece I seamed to be missing was the queued_for_write method.    I'll give it a shot tomorrow and report back.